# Arduino uno R3, making a countdown of 10 seconds using a LCD

Tags: arduino, display, countdown, led, lcd

I am making a simple program using if-else loop to display 10 seconds on a lcd display 16x2 screen. It is a traffic light so when it hits the green LED i want to display 10 seconds and then continue the cycle. My problem here is that the count down goes every seconds and then start the cycle. What i mean is that the initial number is 10 , then the cycles start, then it goes to 9, then the cycle starts, so the problem here is that it doesn't go from 10 to 0 but it goes down every seconds and after every seconds there is a new cycle.

```
enter code here lcd.setCursor(1,0);
                lcd.setCursor(6,1);
                lcd.setCursor(9,1);
                S--;
                if(S<0){
                S=10;
                 }
                if(S>10){
                lcd.setCursor(10,1);
                lcd.print(S);
                }
                else {
                lcd.setCursor(10,1);
                lcd.print(" ");
                lcd.setCursor(11,1);
                lcd.print(S);
                lcd.setCursor(13,1);
                lcd.print(" ");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This questsion is not perfect.

But here is a good example:

```
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Time:");
//lamp green
for (int i=10;i>0;i--){
lcd.setCursor(6,0);
  if (i==9){ //Time: 10, Time: 90 <<this printed without if. Or use a space after i value
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Time:");
  }
lcd.print(i);
delay(1000);
}
//lamp red
for (int i=10;i>0;i--){
lcd.setCursor(6,0);
 if (i==9){ //Time: 10, Time: 90 <<this printed without if. Or use a space after i value
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Time:");
  }
lcd.print(i);
delay(1000);
}
    //lamp green
```

copy this code in a loop, and modify to use.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you it did help a bit one part of your program. But the 9 doesn't go away , is still there.

Comment: Test this: delete the if method, and clear all in display, and print again all data.